# Arduino 12v LED Downlights

Tags: arduino, led, 12v

I have managed to control an RGB LED Strip with an Arduino Uno R3 successfully. I would now like to switch and dim 12v LED Down lights. I am unsure of how to do this the Transformers I have  [are dimmable](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/SAA-APPROVED-LED-NON-DIMMABLE-DIMMABLE-MR16-12V-Power-Supply-Transformer-Driver-/121173447065?pt=AU_Lighting_Fans&var=&hash=item1c36801199) and have 10 watt dimmable LEDS. Would anyone be able to provide information on how to wire them while still being able to dim them manually. Also I have an assortment of electronics bits such as mosfets, transistors etc.

Comment: Why don't you use a conventional RC circuit? You can easily control the discharge profile of the capacitor (and hence the rate of dimming of LED strips connected to the discharge path). It would be more compact as compared to a transformer based circuit and cheap too.

Comment: @VinitShandilya The question states that OP has a 12V LED downlight with a dimmer, which needs to be controlled while retaining the dimmer's manual control. This isn't an LED strip, which OP is already able to control. All this is in the question, did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the "transformer" you refer to is 12VDC - ie it has rectification included so the LEDs are driven by DC.

[image]

So "dimmable LEDs" probably just means "accepts variable voltage DC". If so you should be able to use your existing circuit (which you should add to your post or provide a link to) with the "transformer" DC output, where V+ is now the +ve feed from the 'tranformer' and the LED downlights connect where the LED strip is now. [The circuit  that Emmanuel posted in his now deleted answer](http://blog.dcxn.com/2013/03/03/dimming-a-12v-led-strip-with-an-arduino/) should also work and is likely to be functionally the same as your one. .

With the above arrangement, when you provide full on drive from the Arduino the LEDs will be dimmable manually, and when you provide full brightness with the manual dimmer the LEDs will be dimmable using the Arduino. Dim them both at once and they will interact - but it should do no harm.